# what is wrong with this? SELECT 'TEXT', Num1 From TestTab, 'more text'

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

Just when I thought I was starting to understand SQL, I am completely lost with this.  What is wrong with the syntax of the last SELECT?

```
if (OBJECT_ID('TestTable') IS NOT NULL) drop table TestTable

CREATE TABLE TestTable(
ID  Bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Num1 bigint NOT NULL,
Num2 bigint NULL
)

INSERT INTO TestTable
VALUES (1,2)
SELECT 'TEXT', 'MORE TEXT', 'AND MORE TEXT'
SELECT 'TEXT', Num1 From TestTable
SELECT 'TEXT', Num1 From TestTable, 'MORE TEXT'
```

Comment: so what on earth is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to list all the "columns" (quoted since they're not all actually columns in a table) you want selected *before* specifying their source.

The problem with:

```
SELECT 'TEXT', Num1 From TestTable, 'MORE TEXT'
```

is that you select two columns from `TestTable` then try to select another column. This is not standard SQL syntax. As per the documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) (particularly the syntax diagram), the `from` clause is optional but, if there, it *must* follow the select list.

Once the parser encounters something not part of the select list, no more columns can be selected as part of the current `query-specification`. You can select more columns in *another* `query-specification` (in the `query-expression`) but that must be linked with the previous one with one of `{ UNION [ ALL ] | EXCEPT | INTERSECT }`.

If you want those three columns in a single row, you should use:

```
SELECT 'TEXT', Num1, 'MORE TEXT' From TestTable
```

If you want an *added* row with `MORE TEXT` (I consider this very unlikely given it won't have enough columns for your output), you would have to use two `query-specification` sections linked with `UNION ALL`. Assuming you *had* a value you could use for the `Num1` output column, you could use something like:

```
SELECT 'TEXT' as textcol, Num1 as numcol, From TestTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MORE TEXT' as textcol, 0 as numcol
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT 'TEXT', Num1, 'MORE TEXT' From TestTable

or perhaps more usefull

> SELECT 'TEXT' as col1, Num1 as col2, 'MORE TEXT' as col3 From
>   TestTable

You have to finish your select column list before starting your from clause